# Tomato leaves curling inward

Tags: tomatoes

My tomato plants (don't know which species exactly) when they grow about half a meter tall begin curling inwards their bigger leaves. They're about 5 months old, isn't that too short for them to be dying already? plus I haven't even gotten any tomatoes yet. I live in Qatar which is a sunny and hot desert, perhaps that might have had an effect on the tomato plant? here is a photo of a late stage tomato who's biggest leaves seem to have nearly died, and a younger one who's just begun to have its leaves curling inward:

[image: older tomato]

[image: younger tomato]

they both still have some green leaves which might mean it's not too late yet no?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Curling leaves on a tomato plant can be caused by several things:

1. It can be a viral infection transmitted by white flies (I'm not sure
   if you see anything like white flies near your plants?)
2. Tomato plants can also be triggered into a defense mode caused by
   certain environment conditions such as excessive high temperatures,
   uneven watering, or long periods of dry/arid conditions.

In your photos, it looks like you have your tomatoes in 1 gallon pots -- which are rather small for tomatoes. You also mentioned you're in Qatar which is a hot arid region coupled with the small pots can be the root of your problem. I typically grow tomatoes in 5+ gallon pots and would definitely recommend that to you being in the hot arid region. The soil in pots can easily dry out on a hot  day within hours and you may need to water several times a day to maintain the appropriate moisture level. This [article](https://www.thespruce.com/tips-for-growing-tomatoes-in-containers-848216) has some helpful tips on growing tomatoes in pots.